# InflateException thrown by "?attr/backgroundColor"

Tags: android-layout

I used `android:background="?attr/backgroundColor"` in an app and it threw InflateException, so I tried to simplify the investigation by adding the following lines to a layout file

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/backgroundColor"/>
```

It reproduces the exception:

```
Stack trace: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #187: Binary XML file line #187: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #187: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:775)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:197)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:303)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:284)
```

I can set `android:background` in many other ways without any problem such as:

```
android:background="@color/DarkTranslucent"
```

where `DarkTranslucent` is defined in the app's colors.xml. The binding code in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

```
ActivityFooBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_foo);
```

Could anyone shed some light on this? I wonder if it is bad idea generally to use "?attr".

I checked `backgroundColor` and it is defined in:

```
C:...\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\e96ede1f63007f14d6e9e4e3d2381507\transformed\material-1.10.0\res\values

<attr format="color" name="backgroundColor"/>
```